# No Filters folder in MVC4 Project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am following a tutorial on using the Web Api and it is asking me to expand the Filters folder , the problem is I cant find this folder anywhere within my project.It is needed to add some authorization to the project.Anyone know why the filters folder isnt in my project?.

Comment: Pretend for a minute that you have no knowledge of what you have done so far. Now read this question. Do you think there is enough information to understand what you are talking about? (I would suggest providing information on the steps used to create your project, maybe  a link to the tutorial)

Comment: Really the folder you put it in shouldn't matter too much. I would either just create a folder called that or just put it somewhere else.

Comment: Agree with Ryan. The only folder that really matters in MVC is the Views folder because by convention that's where MVC will look for views. Controllers, Filters, whatever put them wherever you want (but do try to follow convention)

Answer (score 2):

**Internet Application** and **Single Page Application**  project templates for ASP.NET MVC 4 have a Filters folder. If you created the application with some other template, you may not get this folder.

Answer (score -1):

For authorization you can use `Authorize Attribute` at the controller level or action level or at application level. It authorizes the user, and if not redirect to login page as described in `web.config`.